# How do I create a proxy_pass junction by header value in NGINX?

Tags: if-statement, nginx, header, location, openresty

I would like to do something like this:

```
location / {

    if($http_x_my_header == 'some-value') {
        proxy_pass "https://a/";
    }
    # else
    proxy_pass "https://b/";

}
```

Because I know that using "IF" in NGINX can be kind of problematic: How would I solve this following "best practices"?

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/balancer.md

Comment: This approach is not involving Lua and IMO the best one from many others https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59671623/conditionally-map-values-in-nginx-config

Comment: I am using the second approach now (defining a mapping variable) and it works quite well! THX! Maybe you could answer the question so I can mark it as the/my solution. I am also using a lua approach like linked above - but for a different scenario :-)